# JavaFX : How I can Load New Series of Labels ON Event mouseDragExited

Tags: javafx

I am developing a desktop application using javaFx and I have following cases any suggestion how to achieve it.

Case I:
I am adding sequences of labels in HBox with different background colours and adding Hbox to a draggable node... I want to continously generate sequences of labels when it drags.

Refer to link below as an example of the effect I want to achieve.

How to call an event for loading labels dynamically? I have a code to generate label sequences, but how to put it in HBox on DraggedEvent?

[LinkForReferences](http://jbrowse.org/code/JBrowse-1.11.6/?loc=ctgA%3A617..680&tracks=DNA%2CTranscript%2Cvolvox-sorted-vcf&data=sample_data%2Fjson%2Fvolvox&highlight=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be that I did not get your question correctly, but firing an event when a node is dragged is pretty simple:

```
HBox hbox = new Hbox();
hbox.setOnMouseDragReleased((mouseEvent) -> {
    generateLabelSequence();
});
```

This will trigger when the dragging is over... You can also use

```
hbox.setOnMouseDragged(...);
```

If you want it to trigger when the dragging starts, but that's not what you seem to want as your question title states...